# How to interrupt the loop with IPython.embed() inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Using `IPython.embed()` inside a loop for debugging. The loop got to `embed()`, I finished debugging, and wanted to stop the outside loop. Typing `quit()` and then `I` `I` to interrupt kernel doesn't work quickly enough, and I again end up in new `embed()` prompt a moment later.

What's the easiest way to interrupt the entire execution?

Comment: `%raise_exit` will raise an error if you want to break out of the loop. `%kill_embedded` will allow the loop to continue without dropping you back into the IPython prompt.

Comment: @ThomasK Do you mean these commands can be typed inside the embedded shell, before I type quit()? They don't seem to do anything for me with `IPython 5.0.0`.

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. Try upgrading to IPython 5.1; if they still don't work, please open an issue.